# React/Typescript Ag-grid : "Cannot read property 'addOrRemoveCssClass' of undefined"

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In my web app using ag-grid **react ui version 26.0.0**,
**'addOrRemoveCssClass' of undefined** Error was encountered while
trying to move page or click button With Ag-grid Cell Range Selected

**I temporarily solved it :**
Call **gridApi.clearRangeSelection();** before the Event

But I think it is Bug in 26.0.0 because of not lower version.
Is there Different or Better Solution?

React/Typescript Ag-grid IN 26.0.0 reactUi version

- ag-grid-enterprise 26.0.1
- ag-grid-community 26.0.0
- ag-grid-react 26.0.0

````
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addOrRemoveCssClass' of undefined
    at e.onRangeSelectionChanged (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:19303)
    at t.onRangeSelectionChanged (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:21114)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:22624
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:22624
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1350
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1345
    at e.dispatchToListeners (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1355)
    at e.dispatchEvent (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1334)
    ```
````

Comment: I've run into this too, the data changed but if anything is deleted the grid crashes with this error. Looks like there's a few issues with the React UI.

Comment: For me its when using cellClassRules and adding a row